# HTTP запрос через vba с xml данными

Tags: xml, api, vba

Пытаюсь загрузить xml данные на сайт через api, используя access-vba, однако все без результатов.

```html
Public Sub UploadXml(session As String)
Dim testXml As String
testXml = "<?xml version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) & "encoding=" & Chr(34) & "UTF-8" & Chr(34) & "standalone=" & Chr(34) & "yes" & Chr(34) & "?>" _
            & "<apiRequest>" _
            & " <sessionID>session</sessionID>" _
            & " <orderReference>999999999999</orderReference>" _
            & " <orders>" _
            & "     <order>" _
            & "         <areaOfControl>Курьеры</areaOfControl>" _
            & "         <date>28.11.2021</date>" _
            & "         <location>" _
            & "             <name>ИП Тест</name>" _
            & "             <address>Россия, Москва, Скандинавский бульвар, д.6</address> " _
            & "         </location>" _
            & "         <dropWindows>" _
            & "             <dropWindow>" _
            & "                 <start>28.11.2021 08:00</start>" _
            & "                 <end>28.11.2021 12:00</end>" _
            & "             </dropWindow>" _
            & "         </dropWindows>" _
            & "     </order>" _
            & " </orders>" _
            & "</apiRequest>"

Dim xmlhttp As Object
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
Dim myDom As Object
Set myDom = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
myDom.async = False

url = "http://test.maxoptra.com/rest/2/distribution-api/orders/save"
myXMLstr = url & testXml
myDom.Load (myXMLstr)

xmlhttp.Open "post", url, False
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(testXml)
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"

xmlhttp.send myDom.xml
MsgBox xmlhttp.responseText
          
End Sub
```

Возможно ошибка в кодировке xlm.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Есть сайт https://maxoptra.ru/ со своим api https://doc.maxoptra.com/docs/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1966521. Мне нужно отправить POST запрос методом [account-name].maxoptra.com/rest/2/distribution-api/orders/save, в котором структура данных в xml формате. Соответственно сама отправка запроса идет через vba access.